# How to build eclipse-plugin for CDH4 ( 4.2.0 )

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-plugins

is there any one know how to build eclipse-plugin for CDH4 ( 4.2.0 )?
I google it all the morning and only found some tips about 4.1.2 or older version.

My hadoop cluster is build by Cloudera Management, and the latest version of CDH is 4.2.0, I don't know how to build eclipse-plugin, or I should just roll back my CDH version to 4.1.2? if so, how to do that?